# When MyPy is enabled in VsCode does it go through pyright, or is it a seperate thing on its own?

Tags: visual-studio-code, mypy, neovim, pyright

I'm actually trying to use pyright+mypy in Neovim and so I'm inspecting what is going on in VsCode.

I know there is a vscode setting `python.linting.mypyEnabled` and I'm trying to find out what exactly happens when that is so.

Vscode also takes a mypy path which does imply mypy will be a separate process.

I've cloned and searched the Pyright repo and have gotten no results for `mypyEnabled`. This is the same for the VSCode repo.

The vscode-python repo does have evidence of `mypyEnabled`:

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/blob/7e7206701c85cccbb03ece18e10db0ff191ba12f/src/test/linters/common.ts#L181
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/blob/7e7206701c85cccbb03ece18e10db0ff191ba12f/src/client/linters/mypy.ts#L14-L29

It seems mypy is offered through vscode-python. I'm 99% sure of this but I'm not very good at typescript.

One thing that is throwing me off is that `mypyEnabled` is a setting in https://github.com/fannheyward/coc-pyright . "coc-pyright" as far as I know is for "pyright" (as the name would suggest) but as mentioned above `mypyEnabled` is a setting for "vscode-python" and not "pyright".

- How do pyright and mypy coexist when mypy is enabled?
- In VSCode am I right that mypy runs next to pyright via vscode-python? As in, if pyright were completely disabled `mypyEnabled` would still work?
- Optionally: Do you know what why mypyEnabled can be offered via "coc-pyright"?

Thanks!